# jQuery Autocomplete like facebook current city and hometown

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

How would I go about producing an autocomplete-ready input field like the one in this screenshot (from Facebook)? I need the user to be able to type to narrow their choices and then select one option.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can use jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin.

Comment: i searched all over internet look up this solution but not successful

Answer (score 1):

## What if I want to use native HTML5

---

[image]
<sub>(source: [mshcdn.com](http://7.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/html5-logo-1.jpg))</sub>
If you would like to use [HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) instead of [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), here's a quick look of it:

```html
Enter your favorite cartoon character: <br>
<input type="text" name="favCharacter" list="characters">
    <datalist id="characters">
        <option value="Homer Simpson">
        <option value="Bart">
        <option value="Fred Flinstone">
    </datalist>
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah...
```

Whoa! Very simple but it only works on HTML5 browsers (anti-IE).

[*`http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_datalist_tag.cfm`*](https://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_datalist_tag.cfm)

---

## What if I want to use jQuery

If you have to use jQuery, you can the jQuery UI thing:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fuelyourcoding.com](http://fuelyourcoding.com/files/jqueryui.jpg))</sub>

[*`http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/`*](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var tags = [
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "ActionScript",
            "C++"
        ]
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: tags
        });
    })();
</script>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label>Tags: <input id="tags"></label>
</div>
```

<kbd>Live</kbd> demo: [**`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PbjqM/`**](https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PbjqM/)

Now you don't even need any third party plugin!

> Yay! ^_^

Comment: And whatever reason it is, the HTML5 method will not work on Google Chrome, although it supports the `list` attribute.

Comment: yes...it does not work at all

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul, But in Firefox you can see it working though.

Comment: That's impossible, I want to create for other browser too

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul, then use the jQuery method instead.